# How to fix "pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args) _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'" using YOLOv3?

Tags: python, yolo

I am trying to train YOLOv3 using this repository with custom dataset

https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3

I used the weight that recommended in the readme yolov3-spp-ultralytics.pt

When I train I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolov3/train.py", line 431, in <module>
    train(hyp)  # train normally
  File "yolov3/train.py", line 119, in train
    ckpt = torch.load(weights, map_location=device)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 593, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 763, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

Any idea how Yolov3 pickles the file?

Comment: Make sure you have the same versions of pickle and torch used to save the model.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve your problem @Luis Vivas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your yolov3-spp-ultralytics.pt is not correct. Please open it with notepad, I guess the content is a 404 HTML page. The "<" is the beginning of a HTML page.

Comment: I have something similar for another model (`deeplabv3_mobilenet_v3_large-fc3c493d.pth` which I can download fine). However, I could not understand your answer and why it is marked as accepted. Could you be more clear @Yi Zhang?

Comment: How do you make sure it's downloaded fine? what's the size of it?

Comment: I solved my problem by looking at the size of the file. The problem that the download was starting but then it did not succeed (due to proxy) and therefore the size of the file was either 0 or quite small.